# SQL MULTIPLE COUNT AND JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
User_guid | Post Message | Discussion board | Total |

1 | 300 | 25 | 325 |

2 | 15 | 185 | 200 |

3 | 100 | 203 | 303 |
```

but I don't know how.

I have the Post Message result with this Query:

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) as 'Quantidade' , users_entity.name , users_entity.username
FROM river 
JOIN users_entity 
ON river.subject_guid = users_entity.guid 
AND river.action_type = 'create'
AND river.view = 'river/object/thewire/create'
GROUP BY river.subject_guid ORDER BY 'Quantidade' DESC
```

and I have the Discussion result with this Query:

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) as 'Quantidade' , users_entity.name , users_entity.username
FROM river 
JOIN users_entity 
ON river.subject_guid = users_entity.guid 
AND river.action_type = 'reply'
GROUP BY river.subject_guid ORDER BY 'Quantidade' DESC
```

But I don't know how to join these results as rows of the users_entity table. The total interactions should be the sum of the post message and discussion board values. Someone can help me? Thanks.

Comment: You should also explain your current schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell without table structures and sample data (which is why you're getting the down votes), but you probably need something like this:

```
SELECT
  users_entity.name,
  users_entity.username,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN river.action_type = 'create' AND river.view = 'river/object/thewire/create' THEN 1 END) AS Post_Message,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN river.action_type = 'reply' THEN 1 END) AS Discussion_Board
FROM river
JOIN users_entity ON users_entity.guid = river.subject_guid
GROUP BY
  users_entity.name,
  users_entity.username
ORDER BY ???
```

I'm not sure which value you want to `ORDER BY` with the combined query.

Comment: It`s order by users_entity.guid. I`ll try to do this, thank you

Comment: Do you know what should I do to join a count result of another table  in this query?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works for you:

```
SELECT data1.username, data1.count1, data2.count2, data1.count1+data2.count2 from
(
SELECT COUNT( * ) as 'count1' , users_entity.name , users_entity.username
FROM river 
JOIN users_entity 
ON river.subject_guid = users_entity.guid 
AND river.action_type = 'create'
AND river.view = 'river/object/thewire/create'
GROUP BY river.subject_guid ORDER BY 'Quantidade' DESC
) data1,
(
SELECT COUNT( * ) as 'count2' , users_entity.name , users_entity.username
FROM river 
JOIN users_entity 
ON river.subject_guid = users_entity.guid 
AND river.action_type = 'reply'
GROUP BY river.subject_guid ORDER BY 'Quantidade' DESC) data2 where data1.username = data2.username
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try joining the two queries like this

```
SELECT river_create.Quantidade AS create_q, river_reply.Quantidade AS reply_q, river_create.full_name, river_create.u_name, river_create.user_id
    FROM
    (SELECT COUNT( * ) as 'Quantidade' , users_entity.name AS full_name, users_entity.username AS u_name, users_entity.guid AS user_id
         FROM river 
         JOIN users_entity 
         ON river.subject_guid = users_entity.guid 
         AND river.action_type = 'create'
         AND river.view = 'river/object/thewire/create'
         GROUP BY river.subject_guid ORDER BY 'Quantidade' DESC) AS river_create
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT COUNT( * ) as 'Quantidade' , users_entity.name , users_entity.username, users_entity.guid as reply_user_id
         FROM river 
         JOIN users_entity 
         ON river.subject_guid = users_entity.guid 
         AND river.action_type = 'reply'
         GROUP BY river.subject_guid ORDER BY 'Quantidade' DESC) AS river_reply
ON river_create.user_id = river_reply.reply_user_id
```